# CMD Command Prompt DIR Batch File

Tags: batch-file, cmd, dir

I Have a batch file I created below:

```
TITLE Project Folders
DIR S:\"Project Folder 2014\Projects" /T:C /O:-N > S:\MyFolder\dir01.txt
DIR S:\"Project Folder 2014\Projects" /T:W /O:-N > S:\MyFolder\dir02.txt
DIR S:\"Project Folder 2014\Projects" /T:A /O:-N > S:\MyFolder\dir03.txt
S:
CD MyFolder
REN dir01.txt dir01.txt.old
REN dir02.txt dir02.txt.old
REN dir03.txt dir03.txt.old
FINDSTR /V "Volume Directory .. bytes" dir01.txt.old > dir01.txt
FINDSTR /V "Volume Directory .. bytes" dir02.txt.old > dir02.txt
FINDSTR /V "Volume Directory .. bytes" dir03.txt.old > dir03.txt
DEL dir01.txt.old dir02.txt.old dir03.txt.old
PAUSE
```

I would like to know if anyone can help me get closer to having the header and footer removed from a `dir > dir.txt`. I cannot use bare format bc I use the date created, modified, and accessed to monitor each project. I then import these text files into Excel. I am curious if there is a way to do this with a batch, so I will not have to cull the text files each time in Excel.

Comment: Although `S:\"Folder Name"` works, it's better to enclose the whole path: `"S:\Folder Name"`

Comment: [Cross-posted](http://superuser.com/q/974842/87805) at SU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pipe it into a `findstr` with regular expressions so that it pulls lines starting with a number (dates are the first column in the default directory listing).  Something like this:

```
dir "S:\Project Folder 2014\Projects" | findstr /R "^[0-9]" > S:\MyFolder\dir01.txt
```

Comment: I gave it a try but do not understand the logic of the regular expressions, the "^[1-9]" returned 7 random lines. Would you be willing to elaborate, or explain your logic. It seems this would be a systematic kind of thing because the DIR will always return the first 5 lines with the path, Volume label for drive, Volume Serial #, blank line, Directory of Drive:Folder, blank line. Which is why I used the specific FINDSTR to remove the lines.

Comment: Check the output of `findstr /?`.  The regular expression should return all lines that start with a digit (0-9).  (I just corrected the range/class of characters to include zero).  The caret `^` is what tells it to check the beginning of the line for that digit pattern.  Since the lines you reference (volume label, etc) don't start with a digit, this `findstr` command will exclude those undesirable lines.

Comment: Thanks for helping explain. findstr /? is obviously helpful but there is only so much tinkering I can do in one sit down at a time; maybe after lunch I will be able to muster the energy. I am a noob with CMD and just created my first batch files yesterday (sad to say), but there is always room for improvement and time to learn. Thanks again for the help; I just suspected there to be an easier solution. I know this could easily be seen in the Windows Explorer to view these values, but I am trying to automate this process as much as possible. Time to get started with some Excel VBA 8^$

Comment: Please do confirm that it works, which I think it will, and approve the answer if so.  Thanks!

Comment: @MLowry54, that's great.  Can you approve the answer please?

Comment: How do I do that @Marc ?

Comment: @MLowry54, there should be a checkmark next to my answer when you're signed in.  Click that and it should turn green.